# How do I make a button that, when clicked, displays data in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've created a button, along with a table that shows data from my database. However, I want that data to appear only when the button is clicked. So when the button is clicked, I want a random row from a specific table I have in my database appear. [image]

```
`<button id="breakfast2">Breakfast</button>
 <table id="mealTableContainer2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="mealname">Meal Name</th>
                    <th id="mealcalories">Calories</th>
                    <th id="mealtype">Type of Meal</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="mealContainer2"></tbody>
  </table>`
```

The only Javascript I currently have is for getting my database into that table, but I really only want it to appear when I click the breakfast button. I just can't figure out how; if someone could explain it to me very simply, I'd be appreciate it a ton!

```
console.log('Data2 received')
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5000' + "/read-recordsrandom",
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
        var data2 = JSON.parse(response);
        if(data2.msg === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log(data2.meal)
            createMealTable2(data2.meal);
        } else {
            console.log(data2.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert(err);
    }

});
```

}

```
function createMealTable2(data2) { 
var tableHTML2 = " ";
console.log("Test");
for(var i=0; i < data2.length; i++){
    tableHTML2 += "<tr>";
    tableHTML2 += "<td>" + data2[i].mealname + "</td>";
    tableHTML2 += "<td>" + data2[i].mealcalories + "</td>"
    tableHTML2 += "<td>" + data2[i].mealtype + "</td>";
    
    
    tableHTML2 += "</tr>";
}

$('#mealContainer2').html(tableHTML2);
```

}

Comment: A bit broad but if you're happy with using CSS you could create a `hidden` class and then add/remove the class based off whether or not you click a button.

Comment: Using javascript you can add an event listener with: `addEventListener()`. [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Hide it initially then display it

```js
document.getElementById("breakfast2")
  .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("mealTableContainer2").classList.remove('hidden');
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="breakfast2">Breakfast</button>
<table id="mealTableContainer2" class="hidden">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="mealname">Meal Name</th>
      <th id="mealcalories">Calories</th>
      <th id="mealtype">Type of Meal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="mealContainer2"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("mealTableContainer2").hidden = true/false`

Comment: @mplungjan - perhaps, but in this limited scope presented by the OP whatever else may be in play which may effect "hidden" in the "hidden vs visible" context is difficult to determine and factor in.

Comment: This is my mistake for not mentioning it, but I wanted the button to retrieve a piece of data from my database that was random, although I appreciate the suggestion, as it's helped me learn a bit more about buttons

Comment: @Amdaggle THAT part is another question altogether which includes retrieving the data, inserting one row properly in the table and then doing the display; and then what to do for the NEXT row/click etc.

Comment: So I just edited my question,  I have all that code down already, and I have a full list of that table already on my page. I just want a randomizer that picks a specific row on that table and displays it. In the image in my question, that's one row of my table, and it appears randomized whenever I refresh the page, while I want it randomized whenever I click the breakfast button.

Comment: Try not to drastically change a questions possible answers but only clarify what was asked.  It is OK to ask another question for something beyond the original "show on button click" you had.  Suggest you roll back that last edit and create the new question with the specific challenge you have with code included in that new question

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, by default, the table is supposed to be hide. So you can first of all, hide the table with css

Change this line to hide the table

```
<table id="mealTableContainer2" style="display: none;">
```

After that, you will need to add event listener on the button "breakfast" in javascript to display the table on click

```
document.getElementById("breakfast2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("mealTableContainer2").style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: So this is totally my mistake, but I forgot to mention that when the button is clicked, I retrieve a random row on a table. For example, I have a lunch table, and clicking breakfast brings a random mealname, calories and mealtype. This already works when I refresh the page, but I just want it to happen when I click the breakfast button. However, your advice about hiding the table helped a lot, as I was wondering how I would make the table not appear until I click

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can ajax on click

NOTE: the `` are backticks used in [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) delimites and MUST be backticks

```js
$(function() {
  const createMealTable2 = data => {
    $('#mealContainer2')
      .html(data.map(meal => `<tr>
          <td>${meal.mealname}</td>
          <td>${meal.mealcalories}</td>
          <td>${meal.mealtype}</td>
        </tr>`)
        .join("")  
      )
  };

  $("#breakfast2").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000' + "/read-recordsrandom",
      type: 'get',
      success: function(response) {
        var data2 = JSON.parse(response);
        if (data2.msg === "SUCCESS") {
          createMealTable2(data2.meal);
        } else {
          console.log(data2.msg);
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="breakfast2">Breakfast</button>
<table id="mealTableContainer2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="mealname">Meal Name</th>
      <th id="mealcalories">Calories</th>
      <th id="mealtype">Type of Meal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="mealContainer2"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The data seems to be going through, but I'm getting an error  on line 4 at <tr>. I see you have an apostrophe after meal => and after </td>, but whenever I add them, the whole function gives me an error message. Do you think you can help me with this?

Comment: The two backticks I have are NOT apostrophes. They are [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) delimites and MUST be backticks

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't know about them, but I did research them a bit and I'm glad I learned something new.

So I've tested the code once again, and unfortunately, the button didn't work. I didn't get any errors in the code, and I made sure everything was correct in other files. The data didn't come through this time, I'm not sure why. I wish I could post photos in the comments, as I'm not sure what else to explain. I also forgot to mention that I have retrieveData(); and function retrieveData() { above all the code in JS, but I'm sure you knew that already.

Answer (score 0):

You need an event listener that listen for a click and than do the call to your database with asynchronous function. After the answer is returned just put it on the page using createElement or inner text of already existing html element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).